# Re-Presenting Modal View Brings to last VC instead of first

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a Navigation Controller that is presented modally with 4 views in the stack.  The final view has a done button that dismisses the modal view.  When I then present the modal view again, it automatically goes to that last view instead of the first one.  I added a line to pop to first view after dismissed but it adds a weird animation whether I set it to YES or NO.  Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

```
- (void)dismissModalView
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] -4)] animated:YES];
}
```

Update:

This is the method used to present the modal view/navcontroller

```
- (void)showModalView
{
    self.optionsNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.optionsNavController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it looks right. If you want to retain the state of the Navigation controller then don't present it modally as it will get deallocated when you dismiss the view.

Modal views are usually used to present information that only needs to be shown briefly without maintaining the state of the view (i.e. about page, login page, settings page, etc).

Comment: I don't want to retain it.  I want to reset when its dismissed so when user presents it again, it is at the first VC, NOT where user last left off.

Comment: I see, did you try removing the popToViewController line? I don't think you need that. Otherwise can you show us your view hierarchy diagram?

Comment: Ya, if I remove the pop to VC line, it just loads the last view I was at when I had dismissed the navcontroller

Comment: Also, I have a  method that is called in the `viewDidLoad` for the first modal VC that is presented.  However this is only being called the first time I present the modal view, it doesn't happen if I present it again, etc. I think this problem is related.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I'm oversimplifying your issue, but if your need is to pop straight back to the first view controller, perhaps you could give the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method a try instead of `popToViewController:`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem with the dismiss code you posted is, but the following should work:

```
- (void)showModalView
{
    self.optionsNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self.optionsNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.optionsNavController animated:YES];
}
```

Also, `viewDidLoad` is intended to only be called once every time the view is loaded, `viewWillAppear` a